# Cannot resolve Snackbar.make() in setOnclicklistener with lambda

Tags: android, lambda, onclicklistener, snackbar

I was trying to add Snackbar type message for my actions, When i used Snackbar it gives error cannot resolve make().

```
Snackbar.make(this,"Field should not be empty ",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But this gives error

> cannot resolve method 'make()'

After googling and checking on SO i found that it somehow works well with normal setOnclicklistener also i tried it and it worked well in setOnclicklistener of a fragment, But i am using setOnclicklistener with lambda expression that is why here i am pretty confused how to use snackbar because the default method giving error.

**This is what i am doing**

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(view -> login());
```

**And here's my login function**

```
private void login() {

    setError();

    String email = loginUserName.getText().toString();
    String password = loginPassword.getText().toString();

    int err = 0;

    if (!validateEmail(email)) {

        err++;
        Snackbar.make(this,"Enter Valid fields",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //here is the problem
        mTiEmail.setError("Email should be valid !");
    }

    if (!validateFields(password)) {

        err++;
        mTiPassword.setError("Password should not be empty !");
    }

    if (err == 0) {

        loginProcess(email,password);


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter valid details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I hope i am using snackbar correctly if not please let me and also tell why it gives error here **Cannot resolve make()**

Any suggestions or thoughts ?

Comment: Can you show your Snackbar import line?

Comment: **import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;**  is this what you want ?

Comment: Snackbar first parameter is View not context.

Comment: You need to set View instead of Activity/Fragment as first parameter for `make` method. This View is anchor for your snackbar

Comment: Can you please paste buiild.gradle file?

Comment: What view should i use, like i was using normal click listener i can easily implement a view here but that's not the case here

Comment: For snackbar you need to give view on which it will work.. you can give id of your root layout in which you want it to appear.. in first parameter **Refer:** https://imgur.com/a/qU7S1WA

Comment: yes i know that but here i dont have a view and i was not aware about that i can give id of my root layout or can use my loggin button object as a view , but i resolved it know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might call `SnackBar.make()` in Activity range. So `this` is Activity not View. You should change code like this `SnackBar.make(loginButton,...)`.

---

### Update

Compare to Toast, SnackBar is included in Activity. 
So, if you press Home button, Toast is still shown, but snackBar is hidden with the activity.
Because, snackbar is used for showing message to users and interact with users too.

In SnackBar codes in Android source, it finds the parent view group using view parameter. And Snackbar layout is included in the view group.

Comment: i never thought that it can happen this using loginbutton as view , can you explain something on this?

Comment: First, The first parameter of `SnackBar.make()` function is View type, and `loginButton` is Button type which extends View. So `loginButton` is also type of View.

And, concept of SnackBar and is different from toast's.

Answer (score 2):

You can see SnakeBar declaration. First param is View, while you are passing current class object. Perhaps your class is activity.

#### In `Activity`

Either pass `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` which gives root view of current activity. Or pass other view.

#### In `Fragment`

```
Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Sample", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here is the `Snackbar` declaration.

```
@NonNull
public static Snackbar make(@NonNull View view, @NonNull CharSequence text, int duration) {
    ViewGroup parent = findSuitableParent(view);
    if (parent == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.");
    } else {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        SnackbarContentLayout content = (SnackbarContentLayout)inflater.inflate(hasSnackbarButtonStyleAttr(parent.getContext()) ? layout.mtrl_layout_snackbar_include : layout.design_layout_snackbar_include, parent, false);
        Snackbar snackbar = new Snackbar(parent, content, content);
        snackbar.setText(text);
        snackbar.setDuration(duration);
        return snackbar;
    }
}
```

Comment: this also resolves my error and hope it will work well too.